# Safe consumer-producer lock-free ringbuffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free

Assumptions:

- `sizeof(T)` is less than or equal to `sizeof(uint64_t)`
- `T` is aligned
- Target platforms are x86 and x86-64
- There is only one producer thread (only allowed to call `push_back` and full)
- There is only one consumer thread (only allowed to call `pop_front` and `empty`)
- ArraySimple is a dynamically allocated array with fixed size (pointer + size)

Constraints:

- The consumer thread must not block

Question: Is the following RingBuffer safe? If not, what is the least thing that I can add to ensure that data read by consumer is getting mixed up.

```
    template<class T>
    class RingBuffer
        {
        public:
            explicit RingBuffer(size_t N):
                m_offset_read(0),m_offset_write(0),m_data(N)
                {}

            void push_back(T x)
                {
                auto owr=m_offset_write;
                m_data[owr]=x;
                uint32_t N=length();
                m_offset_write=(owr+1)%N;
                }

            T pop_front()
                {
                auto ore=m_offset_read;
                auto ret=m_data[ore];
                uint32_t N=length();
                m_offset_read=(ore+1)%N;
                return ret;
                }

            bool full() const
                {return m_offset_write < m_offset_read;}

            bool empty() const
                {return m_offset_read==m_offset_write;}

            uint32_t length() const noexcept
                {return m_data.length();}

        private:
            volatile uint32_t m_offset_read;
            volatile uint32_t m_offset_write;
            ArraySimple<T> m_data;
        };
```

Comment: How does the consumer know when there's data available?

Comment: @James It calls empty, through polling

Comment: full() is overly pessimistic: when m_offset_write is wrapped, but m_offset_read not yet, it returns true, while we have space in m_data.

Comment: @AlexandrKonovalov Any better idea?